# create nested object from array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a list of link on a website using puppeteer. If the webpage has links, go to that link and get a link.
I could get the links as an array like `myArr`, and now I want to format them to the object.
I have problem creating nested object from array. Can I create nested object from array like this?
Or maybe is there any other good approach?

Expected output:

```
myObjFromArr = [
   {
      "keyword":"a",
      "children":[
         {
            "keyword":"d",
            "children":[
               {
                  "keyword":"k"
               },
               {
                  "keyword":"l"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "keyword":"e",
            "children":[
               {
                  "keyword":"m"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "keyword":"f"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "keyword":"b",
      "children":[
         {
            "keyword":"g"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "keyword":"c",
      "children":[
         {
            "keyword":"h"
         },
         {
            "keyword":"i"
         },
         {
            "keyword":"j"
         }
      ]
   }
  ...
]
```

What I did:

1. get link list array using puppeteer.

```
let count = 0;
let childrenArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
  const keyword = keywords[i];

  if (count < 20) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    await page.goto(`someurl/${keyword}`);
    count++;

    childArray = await page.$$eval(selector, (list) => {
      return list.map((data) =>
        data.href
      );
    });

    childrenArray[i] = childArray;
  }

  let allKeywords = keywords;
  childrenArray[i] = childrenArray[i].map((item) => {
    allKeywords.push(item);
  });
}

await browser.close();
```

2. I've got an array like this:

```
myArr = [['a', 'b' , 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g'],['h', 'i', 'j'],['k', 'l'],['m']...]
```

But not sure how to format this array to create link tree?

Comment: It is a good assignment. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, your `myObjFromArr` is not a valid object.

Comment: I fixed `myObjFromArr`. I also wrote a details of what I want to.  @ilkerkaran

Comment: You still not fix your `myObjFromArr` and are you sure there should be `keyword: 'f'` or just `f` ? Also, you still do not share what have you tried so far and that's why people do not answer you.

Comment: My suggestion: your `myObjFromArr` should be more consistent like this :`[
  {
    "keyword": "a",
    "children": [
      { "keyword": "d", "children": [{ "keyword": "k" }, { "keyword": "l" }] },
      { "keyword": "e", "children": [{ "keyword": "m" }] },
      { "keyword": "f" }
    ]
  },
  { "keyword": "b", "children": [{ "keyword": "g" }] },
  {
    "keyword": "c",
    "children": [{ "keyword": "h" }, { "keyword": "i" }, { "keyword": "j" }]
  }
]
`

Comment: thank you @ikhvjs , I've fixed `myObjFromArr` and added what I did for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function `transform` like below.

Each time you call the recursive function you need to calculate the number of `previous items` and pass it to the recursive again to get the relevant position of the next child array.

```js
data = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"],
  ["g"],
  ["h", "i", "j"],
  ["k", "l"],
  ["m"],
];

const transform = (arr, index) => {
  const store = [];
  if (index < arr.length) {
    let prevItems = 0;

    //get number of previous items
    if (index > 0) {
      for (let j = 0; j < index; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < arr[j].length; k++) {
          prevItems += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr[index].length; i++) {
      const obj = transform(arr, i + prevItems + 1);
      if (obj.length) {
        store.push({ keyword: arr[index][i], children: obj });
      } else {
        store.push({ keyword: arr[index][i] });
      }
    }
  }
  return store;
};

const o = transform(data, 0);

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Thank you @ikhvjs ! This worked perfectly. I didn't know how to write recursive function so I have learned a lot from your code.